# How to resize a css button and keep the inner image to fit?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The button code:

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle('fullscreen');
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.btn {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  margin-left: -32px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

.btn:active {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}

.part1,
.part2 {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather/96/591275-arrow-up-64.png);
  background-size: 32px;
  float: left;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
}

.part1 {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 32px
}

.part2 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.btn.fullscreen {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.btn.fullscreen .part1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.btn.fullscreen .part2 {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <div class="part1"></div>
  <div class="part2"></div>
</div>
```

if I'm changing the width and height of the button to smaller values for example to 44 the result is: (on the left the button in his original size 64 on the right after changing the size to 44).

maybe there is a way to add some variable type int and if I change it will change the button size and will keep everything instead changing the size each time and other things?

[image: button size]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using feather icons and trying to mimic the `maximize-2` icon.

Take a look at this example that uses the SVG that feather icon uses but styles it with some custom CSS to give it a red background with a white border:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const changeFontSize = (difference) => {
    document.body.style.fontSize = (parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.body).fontSize) + difference) + 'px';
    console.log(document.body.style.fontSize);
  };
    document.querySelector('#button-increase').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeFontSize(1);
  }, false);
  document.querySelector('#button-decrease').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    changeFontSize(-1);
  }, false);
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.red-box {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 1em;
  padding: 0.1em;
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="red-box">
  <polyline points="15 3 21 3 21 9"></polyline>
  <polyline points="9 21 3 21 3 15"></polyline>
  <line x1="21" y1="3" x2="14" y2="10"></line>
  <line x1="3" y1="21" x2="10" y2="14"></line>
</svg>
<button type="button" id="button-increase">Increase Font Size</button>
<button type="button" id="button-decrease">Decrease Font Size</button>
```

This makes it so that as the size changes, the image size changes too while keeping the proper positioning.